# Odoo create stock.move.line to reserve stock

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-12

```
product_id = 465
location_id =8
product_qty =1
lot_id = 118
env['stock.move.line'].create(  {
  'company_id':1,
  'picking_id':record.id,
  'lot_id':lot_id,
  'date':record.date,
  'location_dest_id':5,
  'location_id':location_id ,
  'product_uom_qty':product_qty,
  'product_uom_id':32,
  'product_id':product_id
  })
```

I am trying to create stock move line to programmtically create stock.move.line. However, after using this code, stock move line is created but it is not working normally. The Transfer can't be processed even after pressing validating without any error popping. When cancel is pressed, it say `It is not possible to unreserve more products of xxxxx than you have in stock.` After some researching, i am not sure if  I should update stock.quant to reserve the products. Then I added these two lines of code at the bottom of the code above. However, it leads to error that said `'int' object has no attribute 'categ_id'" while evaluating........` Is my code for reservation of stock wrong or is there other way that can make this works. Thanks

```
if env['stock.quant']._get_available_quantity(product_id,location_id, lot_id,strict=True)>=1:
  env['stock.quant']._update_available_quantity(product_id,location_id, -product_qty, lot_id,package_id=False, owner_id=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [_get_available_quantity](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/stock/models/stock_quant.py#L149) function will call [_gather](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c53081f10befd4f1c98e46a450ed3bc71a6246ed/addons/stock/models/stock_quant.py#L114) function which will call the [_get_removal_strategy](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c53081f10befd4f1c98e46a450ed3bc71a6246ed/addons/stock/models/stock_quant.py#L97) function and if you provide the `product_id` as an integer, it will fail to get the `removal_strategy_id` from the product `categ_id`

You may notice that the `_get_available_quantity` function expects a recordset because of the way Odoo defines the variable [rounding](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/stock/models/stock_quant.py#L169).